# Use polar coordinates to evaluate function

Tags: calculus

> To find:

$$\iint_R\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\,dA$$

> where R is first quadrant bounded by $y=0$, $y=x$, $x^2+y^2=4$
>   $$\iint_Rf(r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)r\,dA$$
>
> which is as far as I got -

$$\iint\frac{1}{1+r^2\cos^2\theta +r^2\sin^2\theta}\,dA$$

$$I=\iint \frac{1}{1+r^2}\,dr\,d\theta$$

$$I=\int\tan{^{-1}}r \,d\theta$$

> Where to from here?

Comment: $\, dA = r \, dr \, d \theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So

$$\iint_R\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\,dA$$

Since $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $dA = r \,dr \,d\theta$

$$\iint_R\frac{1}{1+r^2}r \,dr \,d\theta$$

Now, $R$ is the region bounded by $r = [0, 2]$ and $\theta = [0, \pi/4]$. So

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \int_{0}^{2} \frac{r}{1+r^2} \,dr \,d\theta$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \,d\theta \times \int_{0}^{2} \frac{r}{1+r^2} \,dr$$

$$\left( \frac{\pi}{4} \right) \left. \frac{1}{2} \ln(r^2+1)\right|_{r=0}^{2}$$

$$\left( \frac{\pi}{8} \right) \left[ \ln(5) - \ln(1)\right]$$

$$\left( \frac{\pi}{8} \right) \ln(5)$$

Comment: How was this different from mine?

Answer (score 2):

In polar coordinates, the element of surface is $dA=r\,dr\,d\theta$.  Then, upon integrating over the octant $0\le \theta\le \pi/4$ and $0\le r\le 2$, we find

$$\iint_A \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\,dA=\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^2 \frac{r}{1+r^2}\,dr\,d\theta=\frac{\pi}{8}\log(5)$$

Answer (score 0):

your limits for $\theta$ are $0, \pi/4$

$(\pi/4)\tan^{-1} r$